# xml schema check that restriction enumeration value only occrus once

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I am creating a xsd schema for validation of some xml

I would like to restrict the xml so it's not posible to input the same item twice:

```
<branches>
   <branche>Bank</branche>
   <branche>Bank</branche>
</branches>
```

But it must be posible to use 2 different items:

```
<branches>
   <branche>Bank</branche>
   <branche>Insurance</branche>
</branches>
```

So i have the following code:

```
<!-- definition of simple elements -->
    <xs:simpleType name="branche">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Bank" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Insurance" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="branches" minOccurs="0"> <!-- minOccurs becouse i want it to be posible to leave out the whole <branches> tag -->
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="branche" type="branche" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

using the `maxOccurs="1"` does not restrict it to only one value because the 'branche' tag can occur twice.

I want the value (`<branche>value</branche>`) to be unique.

thnx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See examples on identity constraints [here](http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter17.html). Something like:

```
<xs:element name="branches" ...>
  <xs:unique name="...">
    <xs:selector xpath="branche"/>
    <xs:field xpath="."/>
  </xs:key>
</xs:element>
```

Not quite sure about the syntax, but you get the idea.

Comment: I get the basic idea, but it is not working.
I think 'selector' is wrong, and branches must be a complexType becouse it has child elements. I'm still trying to fix this. Will keep you posted

Answer (score 4):

Fixed it by using the following code:

```
<xs:element name="branches" minOccurs="0">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="branche" type="branche" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2" />
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:unique name="brancheUnique">
      <xs:selector xpath="branche"/>
      <xs:field xpath="."/>
   </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

thnx lexicore for pointing me in the right direction